# reset auto increment using prepare stament

Tags: php

I have some problem when using prepare statement because I never use it before.Bellow is my code

```
$maxid = $rowid['product_id'];
$reset = "ALTER TABLE streamyxup AUTO_INCREMENT = $maxid";
$stmt = $conn->PREPARE($reset);
$query->EXECUTE;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code as below to use mysql prepared statement

```
$maxid = $rowid['product_id'];
$reset = "ALTER TABLE streamyxup AUTO_INCREMENT = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($reset);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $maxid);
$stmt->execute();
```

**EDIT**

You are mixing object oriented and procedural way of mysql. change your connection code as below

```
session_start();
$conn = new mysqli("103.6.xxx.xxx", "Miow", "xxow2!", "pe_tm");

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: This is what I want!
You are quite near to my question, but I get  a error massage : 
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in xxxxxx

Comment: May I know need to add some extension like jquery to use the bind_param() function?

Comment: ya ,sure 
    <?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("103.6.xxx.xxx", "Miow", "xxow2!", "pe_tm");
session_start(); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>

Comment: sorry , still having some error
Call to a member function PREPARE() on null

Comment: is it possible my code before using a different way of mysql, so I have to change all those codes to either one of the mysql

Comment: Have you put this code after connection `if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}`?

Comment: ya,sure. I put them when you give me

Comment: Then your prepared statement must work. make sure that `$conn` not changed in between

Comment: I have check all the code, seem like no problem, but still getting an error. now is bind prime on null....
nevermind, once I get the answer I will post here. To avoid newbie did the same mistake with me

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MAX(autoincrement_field) + 1 FROM streamyxup INTO @maxautoinc;
ALTER TABLE streamyxup AUTO_INCREMENT = @maxautoinc;
```

AND

```
  SELECT @max := MAX(ID)+ 1 FROM streamyxup; 

  PREPARE stmt FROM 'ALTER streamyxup ABC AUTO_INCREMENT = ?';
  EXECUTE stmt USING @max;

  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```